# Request Parameter Not Found in formData Containing a JSPDF blob (REACT + SPRING BOOT + MONGODB)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, multipartform-data, jspdf, form-data

I'm trying to send a post request with a pdf blob from react to a springboot api with mongodb. I've successfully done this when posting PNG files from another component but can't recreate with PDFs. I've previously tried to send only the 'file' field within the formData with the rest of the details as @PathVariables bearing the same result; "Required part 'file' is not present."

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(value="/request/approve", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, "application/json"})
public ResponseEntity <Request> updateRequest(@RequestParam("response") String response, @RequestParam("employeeEmail") String employeeEmail,
@RequestParam("month") String month, @RequestParam("year") String year, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
    return new ResponseEntity<Request>(requestService.saveFile(response, employeeEmail, month, year, file), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Service**

```
public Request saveFile(String response, String employeeEmail, String month, String year, MultipartFile file ) throws IOException{
    
    String id = employeeEmail + month +  year;
    System.out.println(id);
    Binary pdf =  new Binary(BsonBinarySubType.BINARY, file.getBytes()); 
    return requestRepository.save(new Request(id, response, month, year, employeeEmail, pdf));
    
}
```

**PDF Generator and Post Request**

```
const FormData = require('form-data')
const fd = new FormData()

const approveRequest = async() =>{

const input = pdfRef.current;
response = "approved";
html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
  const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4', true);
  //added pdf specs here, will add in comments for brevity
  setFile(pdf.output('blob'));
  console.log(file)
  

  fd.append('file', file);
  fd.append('response', response);
  fd.append('employeeEmail', employeeEmail);
  fd.append('month', month);
  fd.append('year', year)

  try{
    const res = api.post('/request/approve', fd);
    console.log(res)
  }catch(err){
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```